# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have the following code:

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO " + tableName +
                "(" + COLUMNS.TILE_ID + "," + COLUMNS.TILE_DATA + "," +
                COLUMNS.TILE_LEVEL + "," + COLUMNS.TILE_COLUMN +
                "," + COLUMNS.TILE_ROW +
                "," + COLUMNS.TILE_IMAGE_FORMAT + "," + COLUMNS.TILE_SOURCE +
                ")";
String values = id + ",?" + "," +
                tile.getLevel() + "," + tile.computeColumn() + "," +
                tile.computeRow() + ",\'" + tile.getFileType().toUpperCase() +
                "\'," + "\'" +
                tile.getSource() + "\');";
        String query = insert + " VALUES (" + values;
        System.out.println(query);
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setBytes(2, tile.getData());
        return this.conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(query);
```

The query value:

> INSERT INTO level1 (TILE_ID,TILE_DATA,TILE_LEVEL,TILE_COLUMN,TILE_ROW,TILE_IMAGE_FORMAT,TILE_SOURCE) VALUES (0,?,1,0,0,'JPG','null');

The **error** I get:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.

My Table:

```
tile_id bigint NOT NULL,
  tile_data bytea,
  tile_level smallint,
  tile_row integer,
  tile_column integer,
  tile_image_format image_format,
  tile_source character varying(30),
  CONSTRAINT level10_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tile_id)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The `tile_image_format` is an enum type I have created myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't posted your stacktrace but your error seems to appear from this:

```
statement.setBytes(2, tile.getData());
```

Which is because you have only one parameter to bind to:

```
INSERT INTO level1 (TILE_ID,TILE_DATA,TILE_LEVEL,TILE_COLUMN,TILE_ROW,TILE_IMAGE_FORMAT,TILE_SOURCE) VALUES (0,?,1,0,0,'JPG','null');
```

The fact that the parameter is at position 2 in the values list is not what counts. It's the fact that it's the first place holder that matters. So your code should be,

```
statement.setBytes(1, tile.getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to e4c5 answer, I fixed my code as following:

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO " + tableName +
                "(" + COLUMNS.TILE_ID + "," + COLUMNS.TILE_DATA + "," +
                COLUMNS.TILE_LEVEL + "," + COLUMNS.TILE_COLUMN +
                "," + COLUMNS.TILE_ROW +
                "," + COLUMNS.TILE_IMAGE_FORMAT + "," + COLUMNS.TILE_SOURCE +
                ")";
String values = id + ",?" + "," +
                tile.getLevel() + "," + tile.computeColumn() + "," +
                tile.computeRow() + ",\'" + tile.getFileType().toUpperCase() +
                "\'," + "\'" +
                tile.getSource() + "\');";
String query = insert + " VALUES (" + values;
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setBytes(1, tile.getData());
int result = statement.executeUpdate();
statement.close();
return result;
```

> The fact that the parameter is at position 2 in the values list is not what counts. It's the fact that it's the first place holder that matters.